# Java DOM setAttribute not working

Tags: java, xml, dom, setattribute

Can someone tell me why this isn't work? It's driving me crazy.

myFile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root date="oldValue" />
```

Java Code

```
try {
    Document doc = builder.parse(new File("myFile.xml"));
    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
    System.out.println("date: " + root.getAttribute("date") + "\n");
    root.setAttribute("date", "test");
    System.out.println("date: " + root.getAttribute("date"));
}  catch (Exception e)  {
    System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
}
```

Output

```
oldValue
oldValue
```

No matter what I do, I cannot get my code to write to the XML file... I've tried performing the setAttribute() function on child nodes of the root. I've tried just removing root... Nothing works. I'm beyond frustrated, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have exact same issue. Does anyone have the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you following the same code as below? This works for me (with the same content in myFile.xml):

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

    try{
        Document doc = builder.parse(new File("myFile.xml"));
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        System.out.println("date: " + root.getAttribute("date") + "\n");
        root.setAttribute("date", "test");
        System.out.println("date: " + root.getAttribute("date"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for kicks, what version of Java are you running?

Comment: Yes I am following the same code. This is why it's so frustrating. I know that it's able to access the file because it can read it fine.. It's just not able to write to it. I'm running 1.5_012

Answer (score 1):

Your code was just writing to the Element object, as opposed to the .xml file (However, when I ran your code my output was:

```
             date: oldValue

             date: test
```

To write to the .xml file,  use the following.

```
try
      {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new File("myFile.xml"));

        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        System.out.println("date: " + root.getAttribute("date") + "\n");
        root.setAttribute("date", "test");

        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("myFile.xml"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);


        System.out.println("date: " + root.getAttribute("date"));

      }
    catch (TransformerException | SAXException | ParserConfigurationException | IOException e )
      {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```